# ASPNET Core 3.1 RedirectResult no longer works in Production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an `asp.net` core application that is hosted at SmarterAsp.net.   Basically, I'm inserting data into a sql db with an `IActionResult` method (see below).   After the db insert, I redirect to a page which shows the inserted data.  Everything previously worked in production.  Everything still works locally.

Now, when I run in Production, the `NewValueArray` fires, the db is updated but then I get back a `"Page not found 404 error"` for `www.mydomain.com/SiteAssessmentValue/Index?id=##"` (where ## is the route value for the assessment).

Two things have changed.

One, I updated from Core 2.2 to Core 3.1.

I also believe there have been changes by `SmarterAsp.net` on their servers.  It only does this in production.  I don't know how to troubleshoot this.   Even if I change the Redirect to something innocuous like www.google.com, I get the same message.

For some reason, the RedirectResult no longer works.   Any idea why that could be? I don't know how to fix something that I can't see what's failing since it only happens in production.

```
public IActionResult NewValueArray(int? assessmentId)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(assessmentId) != 0)
    {
        var data = (
            from oa in _context.OutcomeAreas
            join oat in _context.OutcomeAttributes on oa.Id equals oat.OutcomeAreaId
            join oas in _context.OutcomeAttributeScales on oat.Id equals oas.AttributeId

            select new
            {
                AreaActive = oa.Active,
                AttributeActive = oat.Active,
                ScaleActive = oas.Active,
                ScaleDescription = oas.Description,
                oas.ScaleType,
                oa.OrganizationId,
                oas.Id
            }).ToList().Where(z => z.OrganizationId == HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("curOrgId")
                && z.AreaActive == true && z.AttributeActive==true & z.ScaleActive==true);

        foreach (var SiteId in data)
        {
            decimal curScaleFactor;
            if (SiteId.ScaleType == "AA")
            {
                curScaleFactor = 0.2m;
            }
            else
            {
                curScaleFactor = 1.0m;
            }

            var entityValue = new SiteAssessmentValue
            {
                AssessmentId = Convert.ToInt32(assessmentId),
                ItemId = SiteId.Id,
                Description = SiteId.ScaleDescription,
                Active = true,
                ScaleFactor = curScaleFactor,
                ActiveScaleFactor = 1.0m,
                ModBy = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ToString(),
                ModDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            // Add the entity.
            _context.SiteAssessmentValue.Add(entityValue);
            // Insert the entities in the database.
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Update the SiteAssessmentValue table with the current ActiveScaleFactor
        var id = new SqlParameter("@assessmentId", assessmentId);
        _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC savActiveScaleFactor_upd @assessmentId", id);
    }
    return Redirect(Url.Content("~/SiteAssessmentValues/Index?id=")+assessmentId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue at the host site.  They reinstalled core 3.1.  Sorry for the bother.